# Fire away (please)

Tags: idioms, expressions, phrases

According to the dictionary definition:

[Fire away](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fire-away) 
is used for giving sb permission to ask a question.

- Can I ask you a question? --- Fire away.

I was wondering if a university professor asks me:

> Can I ask you a question?

and a student replies:

> "fire away". OR "fire away please".

it would be considered impolite or not? (Supposing that the student and the teacher are not like friends and there is a formal atmosphere between them.)
If so, then what would be its alternative in formal speech?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think "Fire away" is *impolite*, but it's very informal.  A student might say it to a professor if they had a very friendly, informal relationship.

More formal ways to say it might be

- Certainly.
- Of course.
- Please do.
- Feel free.  (This one is more informal than the others, but not as informal as *Fire away*, in my opinion.)

Answer (score 3):

The polite way to answer the professor would be something like "Yes, certainly" or "Yes, of course". You would only use "Fire away" when talking informally with a friend or relative - it means approximately "Go on - shoot your question at me."